# Kotlin nullable generic

Tags: kotlin, generics, nullable

I am not understand why this code not working

```
    class nullableGenericA<T: Any?>{
        fun someMethod(v: T){}
        fun someMethod(){
            someMethod(null)
        }
    }
```

error: "Null can not be a value of a non-null type T".
How it works? If nullable is not part of type why works this

```
   class NullableGenericB<T>(val list: ArrayList<T>){
       fun add(obj: T){
           list.add(obj)
       }
   }

   fun testNullableGenericB(){
       NullableGenericB<String?>(ArrayList()).add(null)
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your generic type is not necessarily nullable. It only has an upper bound of allowing nullable, but it is not constrained to be nullable. Since `T` could possibly be non-nullable, it is not safe to pass `null` as `T`. For example, someone could create an instance of your class with non-nullable type:

```
val nonNullableA = NullableGenericA<String>()
```

If you want to design it so you can always use nullables for the generic type, then you should use `T?` at the use sites where it is acceptable. Then, even if `T` is non-nullable, a nullable version of `T` is used at the function site.

```
class NullableGenericA<T>{
    fun someMethod(v: T?) {}

    fun someMethod() {
        someMethod(null)
    }

    fun somethingThatReturnsNullableT(): T? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that you have seen my reply on my deleted answer, just wanted to thank you for the explaining and linking the not-nullable generic feature

Comment: @Steyrix, I saw it, you're welcome